# Using CGAL on iOS (or... CGAL alternatives for iOS)

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry

I'm working on a computer-graphics related application, mainly designed for iOS devices. Generally, the application concerns 3D sketching & modeling. I'm all set on a graphical engine (based on OpenGL). 
Extensive research indicated that CGAL is practically the best solution out there, for some of the tough problems with which I'm dealing. Specifically at this moment I'm looking for a 3D surface mesh generation library, but without a doubt many other geometry-related problems will appear on the way (such as point location, line intersection, etc).
Problem is, that CGAL does not support iOS (as stated in the CGAL site & docs). I tried finding some information as per what are the problems in the interaction between the two, but all I found is a couple of short "I'm-not-exactly-sure-why-but-it-isn't-supposed-to-work" kind of answers.

Ideally, I'm looking for one of the two:
1. Any input about trying to integrate CGAL on iOS (either successfully or not).
2. A decent geometry-related alternative library, iOS compatible, which will provide solution to the types of problems described above (preferably open-sources, but this part is compressible).